# DataBase Error InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, innodb

While checking the error logs in my wordpress site I would get the following for the mysql logs.

```
161120  6:41:58  InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table databasename/wp_wfHoover
InnoDB: because the .ibd file is missing.  For help, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
161120  6:41:58 [ERROR] MySQL is trying to open a table handle but the .ibd file for
table databasename/wp_wfHoover does not exist.
Have you deleted the .ibd file from the database directory under
the MySQL datadir, or have you used DISCARD TABLESPACE?
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
```

What is the problem here? My site is hosted on an ubuntu server using apache2.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd like to mention that my site is hosted on an ubuntu server using apache2

Comment: It is saying that a file is missing or otherwise inaccessible.  Is it a Cloud service?  If so, complain to them.

Comment: Read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104554/ibd-file-is-missing-and-alter-table-discard-tablespace-crashing-the-server

Comment: it's hosted on dropbox Rick.. thanks for suggesting, ill ask them out..